# How to make Date call create upper bound for time, if no time is specified?

Tags: javascript

I have an api where I need to generate a date object based on data passed form frontend. like:

```
new Date("Thu Jul 08 2021")
```

The above code results in the following output:

```
Thu Jul 08 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0545
```

As you can see the time is set to 00:00:00 becuase i have not specified any. But I want the time to be set to the maxium if  no time is specified like:

```
Thu Jul 08 2021 23:59:59 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time)
```

How may I use Date class to do so?

Comment: new Date("Thu Jul 08 2021 23:59:59");

Comment: @T.Shah in your solution you have passed the time. My question regarding how to do so without passing time and only date. Like: new Date("Thu Jul 08 2021")